# Does GTK ListView not allow space after the last column?

Tags: gtk

I have searched Google Images for "GTK ListView" and I could not see a single example of a GTK ListView having an empty space after the last column, like that of .NET's as below. Is that impossible with GTK?

[image]

Comment: Can't you put labels with nothing in them (empty strings)?

Comment: The thing I am trying to do is dragging from the empty area to select multiple items. If I put an empty column there, wouldn't that start item dragging instead?

Comment: Ok, I would suggest updating your question to add more details about what you are trying to achieve. I would help future readers.